# alias not working in mac

Tags: macos, alias

I get this error when I try to set alias on the mac machine. Did any one faced this problem.

```
sh-3.2# alias lf 'ls -F'
sh: alias: lf: not found
sh: alias: ls -F: not found
sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing an equal symbol. It should read:

alias lf='ls -F'

Comment: This is the correct way to do it.  Are there some shells that accept aliases without an '='?

Comment: @RandyHoward - I believe the OP's syntax is valid in `tcsh` and perhaps `csh` as well...